# Trying to get value determined by javascript using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

As title says, I am currently trying to acquire a dynamic value. I am lost as originally I was using beautiful soup and found out the value was dynamic.
Here are how the values are determined

```
        .call({from: from})
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log("Node Price (Wei AVAX): " + res);
            const avax = Number(Web3.utils.fromWei(res, 'ether'));
            console.log("Node Price (AVAX): " + avax);
            const items = document.querySelectorAll(".node-info-price-avax");
            items.forEach(i => {
                i.innerHTML = avax.toFixed(2) + " AVAX";
            });
        })
```

Then here is how its displayed,

```
<span class="node-info-price-avax">27.88 AVAX</span>
```

I've been watching tutorials and reading over guides all day and can not for the love of me figure out how to acquire said value.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty detailed video that did exactly what I was looking for.
The solution was finding the data I needed and copying the xpath by using `find_element`, then I appened it to a list and used pandas to make it look pretty. Here is the finished code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://playa3ull.games")

node_data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wpb_wrapper')

data_list = []

for data in node_data:
    node_price = data.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pb-node-info-table"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/span[1]').text
    nodes_sold = data.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pb-node-info-table"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]').text
    token_price = data.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pb-node-info-table"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/span[2]').text
    data_item = {
        'Node Price': node_price,
        'Nodes Sold': nodes_sold,
        'Token Price': token_price
    }
    data_list.append(data_item)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df_last = df[-1]
print(df_last)
```

Here is the link for a more detailed explanation: [youtube.com/watch?v=lTypMlVBFM4](http://youtube.com/watch?v=lTypMlVBFM4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31057285)

Comment: thank you. I edited the answer for more detail